# Need to download lots of files, Whats the most lightweight download manager?

Tags: windows-7, download, download-manager

I need to download 30000+ .mp3 files! each of them are ~200 kb..
I tried to download all of them or in 6 sets (5000 files each time) with Internet Download Manager but it freezes.. Which download manager could handle this much files?

Links:
http://www.everyayah.com/data/Alafasy_64kbps/

http://www.everyayah.com/data/Maher_AlMuaiqly_64kbps/

Comment: Post the url, I'll get them with linux, 7z them (store archive) and upload it somewhere. If that's a solution. As an answer: Go with wget. If possible. The URL would help us a lot.

Comment: Wow I feel like I'm asking too much. I've updated the post above with 2 links each containing 6300+ links. Thanks for the offer Shiki

Comment: If you can manage it, ask someone on the other end to zip them up for you. You won't get much additional compression (if any), but they will transfer _much_ faster as a unit.

Comment: You are not asking too much, we just want to help. :)

Answer (score 4):

I routinely do 3k <.5MB files, and I use [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/).

I can't say if there is better or more light weight solutions out there, but, this works and does what I need - I go page by page, right click, add all to IDM, then when I finished, I highlight them all in IDM and do start!

I have never done 30k all in one go, but, I hope this helps!

Comment: FDM is a good general purpose download manager. 30k might be pushing it, though...

Comment: I tried FDM and its okay though it fatal-crashes a lot when I add the links, I tried to add 6000 links each time and its still crashing :(

Comment: @Omar - Do you get impatient or do you leave it running? 6k is a hell of a lot for any program... possibly leave it running to get it's way through your list.

Comment: @WilliamHilsum Haha no I obviously leave it running for a long time though when I do anything after a looong time I get the fatal-crash dialog

Comment: @Omar - It depends what "fatal crash" dialog it is... if it is a single threaded application, the UI will be unresponsive and look like it has crashed - it will most likely come back to life after finishing... but, if you click on it, it will appear dead/unresponsive/crashed... If you have time to test, give it a 6k list and leave it overnight and see if it has worked by morning. If it hasn't I am out of ideas and clearly this program is not for you!

Comment: Wget is much better. Use the mirror option. As I said, I can mirror it for you, but it will take some time. When I'm done, I'll post the 7z.

Answer (score 3):

As @Shiki already said: wget

`wget -i` will read all URLs from external files and process them

Answer (score 1):

Jdownloader http://jdownloader.org/download/index   Is an interesting, multi-platform Java downloader that is being developed continually.  It is Not lightweight at all, and could be a security risk for all I know. 30k would probably have to be done in sections.  but it has a way to backup the list, and load lists in.  Its main design seems to be more about downloading from "public servers", but it works good for normal stuff.

I have seen 5000 items in it, but that was because I asked it to analise a link that went on forever, ooops.

Answer (score 1):

I use curl (http://curl.haxx.se/). It has a bunch of good features for mass downloads. It allows you to specify many files on one invocation, like this:

```
CURL.EXE http://example.com/file[1-10].mp3
```

That will download "file1.mp3", "file2.mp3", and so on.

I've used it to download many files, but not 5,000. However, in principle it should work.